# Entire scene gets pitch black when switching from Cycles to Eevee

Tags: camera, eevee-render-engine, lighting

[image]

I checked the strength of all the lights and even have cranked the strength up to at least 1000 but the entire scene is still pitch black. Everything works fine in Cycles. I tried all sorts of measures to no avail.

The lights simply won't show up in Eevee, whereas in Cycles it is perfect.

Comment: Do you have a transparent object? It will appear black by default

Comment: switch setups with https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272459/render-cycles-is-suddenly-all-black