# Render - Cycles is suddenly all black

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Rendering with **Cycles** was working nice, but suddenly it stopped working and resulting renders are all black. Eevee render works fine (but it's not suitable for better rendering). It affects all cameras (I have about 6 of them) and it happened at once.

- View Layer Properties - `Surfaces` *are enabled*
- Objects and lights are *not* disabled in the Outliner
- There are *plenty of lights* in the scene.
- Render Layers `Image` *is* connected to the Composite `Image` in the Compositor
  [image]
- In addition to that, I have only one "Scene" scene and one "View Layer" layer
- Render Properties -> Film `Exposure` is set to `1.00`
- Clipping distance of camera(s) are set well beyond the scene (0.1-1000m).

EDIT:

- tried to uncheck `Compositing` and `Sequencer` in Output Properties -> `Post Processing`
- checked, that there's no large object blocking camera view. Also, it affects *all* cameras.
- I *don't* have `Render Region` enabled in *N Panel* -> *View* -> *View*.

I found all above on the internet as possibly related to this issue, but all checks in my scene.
Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: switch setups with https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272456/the-entire-scene-gets-pitch-black-as-soon-as-i-switch-from-cycles-to-evee-i-hav

Comment: I don't get what you mean by typing here "switch setup with x" and typing there "switch setups with..." me

Comment: its called linking threads with similar issues which may be helpful for us to find the underlying problem.

Comment: OK, I get that linking, that's understandable. I wasn't and still not sure what (if) you're asking me to do.